# Synapse Analytics - Can't see the tables list in the dedicated sql pool

Tags: azure-synapse

In Synapse Analytics portal my account has this permission for the scope Workspace:
Synapse Administrator
Synapse SQL Administrator

I can execute pipelines. but I can't see the list of the objects such as tables, views, ... in the DB
[image]

In SSMS I can connect to the sql pool and browse object.
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks it is a good answer, but in my case it was not the issue.
My Azure AD account is admin of the Synapse workspace but was not a user in the pool. I did not create this pool.
By default it seems that only the user who creates the pool will be added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> You will experience this because Azure Synapse SQL pool named - `sspocbi` is paused. Make sure the SQL Pool named `sspocbi` is **online** to see the tables.

For your understanding I have two Azure Synapse SQL pools named - `chepra` and `SQLPOOL1`.

where SQL Pool named `chepra` is **online** and `SQLPOOL1` is **paused**.

[image]

When check the tables in the databases for the the SQL Pool which is online you can view the tables and for SQL Pool which is paused doesn't show any tables:

[image]

Now I tried to **resume** the Azure Synapse SQL pool named `SQLPOOL1`

[image].

**A FEW MINUTES LATER**: It's shown the tables.

[image]

If the database is online, you can view the tables. Else you will see the cross mark which denotes you cannot view the tables.