# Azure Synapse - can't see dedicated server tables

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm attempting this quickstart, have got to this point but I've come unstuck.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-sql-pool

Second step "2.Go to SQLPOOL1 > Tables."

I can't see a database or dbo.NYCtaxi tables in any tab or menu of the UI.

**What I expected**

-somehere in the red rectangle below, to see a database directory structure like the first screenshot in this SO [Synapse Analytics - Can't see the tables list in the dedicated sql pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66443813/synapse-analytics-cant-see-the-tables-list-in-the-dedicated-sql-pool)

[image: missing database and tables]

**What I have tried**

-I'm able to query them using SQL script connected to SQLPOOL1[server.]SQLPOOL1[database], but can't browse them.

-refreshing all the pages\workspaces

-checking that the status for this pool is online (it is)

-double-clicking the SQLPOOL1 link in the Manage tab of the UI. I thought it might open a list of tables (it only shows the properties)

-this SO [Synapse Analytics - Can't see the tables list in the dedicated sql pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66443813/synapse-analytics-cant-see-the-tables-list-in-the-dedicated-sql-pool)

Answer (score 0):

Found it...I was looking at the wrong tab
[image]